# UNION and GROUP BY in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, group-by, union

I need help for create a View in SQL Server. I have some thing like this

```
    SELECT MemberId,
           Name,
           SUM(TotalSales) as SalesAmount,
           CreatedOn
    FROM (
             (SELECT MAX(0) AS MemberId,
                     MAX('Others') AS Name,
                     SUM(TotalSales) AS SalesAmount,
                     CreatedOn
              FROM   {...} AS A
              GROUP  BY CreatedOn
             )
             UNION
             (SELECT MemberId,
                     Name,
                     SUM(TotalSales) AS SalesAmount,
                     CreatedOn
              FROM   {...} AS D
              GROUP BY MemberId, Name, CreatedOn            
         )
    ) AS E
    GROUP BY MemberId, Name, CreatedOn
```

But when I save the View, the Microsoft SQL Server Management show me this error:

[image]

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think view don't allow grouping

Comment: Can you put the error image directly in your question, or put the error text in your question?

Comment: Could you show the complete query ?

Comment: @SandipPatel I think they do

Comment: @hatchet New user cant do that. So you may help him editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT  MemberId, Name, SUM(SalesAmount) as SalesAmount, CreatedOn 
FROM ( 
    SELECT MAX(0) AS MemberId, 
           MAX('Others') AS Name, 
           SUM(TotalSales) AS SalesAmount, CreatedOn
    FROM
       {...} AS A
    GROUP BY CreatedOn

    UNION

    SELECT MemberId, Name, 
           SUM(TotalSales) AS SalesAmount, CreatedOn
    FROM
        {...} AS D
    GROUP BY MemberId, Name, CreatedOn            

 ) AS E
 GROUP BY MemberId, Name, CreatedOn
```

Comment: So you're saying to simply remove the parenthesis from around the two selects that get unioned?

Comment: @hatchet Hmm, I don't know what I was thinking... beyond that there is also a small correction:  `SUM(TotalSales)` has become `SUM(SalesAmount)`. Removing the parentheses shouldn't make any difference though.

Comment: Beside the wrong name on `TotalSales` the query seem to be ok. http://rextester.com/QCFS96639

Comment: Not sure why it is downvote.. Looks like parenthesis is the actual issue